# In echarts, after the node is dragged and scaled, the node returns to its original position

Tags: echarts

I am a new user of echarts. When I set coordinateSystem: 'cartesian2d', the roam property does not take effect, so I use dataZoom to scale. However, I found that after I drag the node and scale it, the node returns to its original position. Why is this, and is there any solution? Also, I would like to ask which version of the draggable attribute is in effect. Thank you!
Here is part of my code

```
var dom = document.getElementById('chart-container');
var myChart = echarts.init(dom, null, {
  renderer: 'canvas',
  useDirtyRect: false
});

var app = {};

var option;

option = {
  title: {
    text: 'Basic Graph'
  },
  tooltip: {},
  xAxis: {
    min: 0,
    max: 400,
    type: 'value',
    axisLine: { onZero: false },
    show: true
  },
  yAxis: {
    min: 0,
    max: 200,
    type: 'value',
    axisLine: { onZero: false },
    show: true
  },
  dataZoom: [{
    type: 'inside',
    xAxisIndex: [0],
    filterMode: 'empty'
  }, {
    type: 'inside',
    yAxisIndex: [0],
    filterMode: 'empty'
  }],
  series: [{
    type: 'graph',
    coordinateSystem: 'cartesian2d',
    layout: 'none',
    symbolSize: 50,
    // roam: true,
    label: {
      show: true
    },
    edgeSymbol: ['circle', 'arrow'],
    edgeSymbolSize: [4, 10],
    data: [{
      name: 'A',
      symbol: 'rect',
      symbolSize: [50, 30],
      value: [100, 100]
    }, {
      name: 'B',
      symbol: 'circle',
      symbolSize: 40,
      value: [300, 100]
    }],
    links: [{
      source: 'A',
      target: 'B'
    }],
    lineStyle: {
      opacity: 0.9,
      width: 2,
      curveness: 0
    },
    draggable: true
  }]
};

if (option && typeof option === 'object') {
  myChart.setOption(option);
}

window.addEventListener('resize', myChart.resize);
```

Answer (score 1):

Apparently there is a different kind of mechanism to realize dragging and it is neccessary to update the series data on every drag event. From the [official documentation](https://echarts.apache.org/handbook/en/how-to/interaction/drag/):

[image: dragging function]

Heres the code of the [official example](https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=line-draggable):

```js
import * as echarts from 'echarts';

var chartDom = document.getElementById('main');
var myChart = echarts.init(chartDom);
var option;

const symbolSize = 20;
const data = [
  [40, -10],
  [-30, -5],
  [-76.5, 20],
  [-63.5, 40],
  [-22.1, 50]
];
option = {
  title: {
    text: 'Try Dragging these Points',
    left: 'center'
  },
  tooltip: {
    triggerOn: 'none',
    formatter: function (params) {
      return (
        'X: ' +
        params.data[0].toFixed(2) +
        '<br>Y: ' +
        params.data[1].toFixed(2)
      );
    }
  },
  grid: {
    top: '8%',
    bottom: '12%'
  },
  xAxis: {
    min: -100,
    max: 70,
    type: 'value',
    axisLine: { onZero: false }
  },
  yAxis: {
    min: -30,
    max: 60,
    type: 'value',
    axisLine: { onZero: false }
  },
  dataZoom: [
    {
      type: 'slider',
      xAxisIndex: 0,
      filterMode: 'none'
    },
    {
      type: 'slider',
      yAxisIndex: 0,
      filterMode: 'none'
    },
    {
      type: 'inside',
      xAxisIndex: 0,
      filterMode: 'none'
    },
    {
      type: 'inside',
      yAxisIndex: 0,
      filterMode: 'none'
    }
  ],
  series: [
    {
      id: 'a',
      type: 'line',
      smooth: true,
      symbolSize: symbolSize,
      data: data
    }
  ]
};
setTimeout(function () {
  // Add shadow circles (which is not visible) to enable drag.
  myChart.setOption({
    graphic: data.map(function (item, dataIndex) {
      return {
        type: 'circle',
        position: myChart.convertToPixel('grid', item),
        shape: {
          cx: 0,
          cy: 0,
          r: symbolSize / 2
        },
        invisible: true,
        draggable: true,
        ondrag: function (dx, dy) {
          onPointDragging(dataIndex, [this.x, this.y]);
        },
        onmousemove: function () {
          showTooltip(dataIndex);
        },
        onmouseout: function () {
          hideTooltip(dataIndex);
        },
        z: 100
      };
    })
  });
}, 0);
window.addEventListener('resize', updatePosition);
myChart.on('dataZoom', updatePosition);
function updatePosition() {
  myChart.setOption({
    graphic: data.map(function (item, dataIndex) {
      return {
        position: myChart.convertToPixel('grid', item)
      };
    })
  });
}
function showTooltip(dataIndex) {
  myChart.dispatchAction({
    type: 'showTip',
    seriesIndex: 0,
    dataIndex: dataIndex
  });
}
function hideTooltip(dataIndex) {
  myChart.dispatchAction({
    type: 'hideTip'
  });
}
function onPointDragging(dataIndex, pos) {
  data[dataIndex] = myChart.convertFromPixel('grid', pos);
  // Update data
  myChart.setOption({
    series: [
      {
        id: 'a',
        data: data
      }
    ]
  });
}

option && myChart.setOption(option);
```

As far as I can see there is currently no `ondrag` event for the basic series. Also the roam property seems to be not working at all for me which might be a bug.